# How to add a toolbar to a window with custom titlebar

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6

I have modelled my work with @S. Nick's answer in this post [PyQt: How to create custom combined titlebar and menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57569044/pyqt-how-to-create-custom-combined-titlebar-and-menubar)

I have added a lot of improvements with the titlebar. However, am now having an issue with adding toolbar to it's proper location.

[custom titlebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnFfK.png)
as you can see, the vertical sequence is:

- titlebar
- tab widget
- toolbar

how do i make it show as:

- titlebar
- toolbar
- tab widget

**EDIT:**

- i updated my previous code with **@A. Herlas** solution [10/13/2022]
- finally got to fix the issue with the mouse cursor not exactly centering on the
  titlebar if window maximized and then moused dragged [10/25/2022]

Code:

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc
from PySide6 import QtGui as qtg


class TitleBar(qtw.QWidget):
    height = 35
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(parent)

        self.nav_maximize = """
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"] {
                image: url(./icons/nav_maximize.png);
                background: #161a21;
                border: nobutton_stylene;
                padding-right: 3px; 
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]:hover {
                image: url(./icons/colored_maximize.png);
                background: #161a21;
                border: none;
            }
        """

        self.nav_normal =  """
                QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]{
                    image: url(./icons/nav_normal.png);
                    background: #161a21;
                    border: none;
                    
                }
                QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]:hover{
                    image: url(./icons/colored_normal.png);
                    background: #161a21;
                    border: none;
                    
                }
            """

        ### for window movement ###
        self.prevGeo = self.geometry()
        self.pressing = False
        self.maximizedWindow=False
        ### [ end ] ###
        
        self.current_editor = self.parent().create_editor()
        self.current_editor.setFocus()
        self.text_editors = []
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True) 
        self.tabs.tabBar().setMovable(True)

        self.parent()._createActions()
        self.parent()._connectActions()
        
        self.layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,10,0) 
        
        self.menubar = qtw.QMenuBar()
  
        file_menu = self.menubar.addMenu('File')
        file_menu.addAction(self.parent().new_action)
        file_menu.addAction(self.parent().open_action)
        file_menu.addAction(self.parent().save_action)
        file_menu.addSeparator()
        file_menu.addAction(self.parent().exit_action)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.menubar) 

        self.window_title = qtw.QLabel("Visual Studio Code") # Window title
        self.window_title.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.window_title.setAccessibleName("lbl_title") 
        self.window_title.setFixedHeight(self.height)
        self.layout.addStretch(1) # this stretches the self.window_title qlabel to take-up all the remaining space
        self.layout.addWidget(self.window_title)

        self.setSizePolicy(qtw.QSizePolicy.Expanding, qtw.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.maximizedWindow=False
       
        self.closeButton = qtw.QToolButton() 
        self.closeButton.setAccessibleName("btn_close")                           
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.onClickClose)

        self.maxButton = qtw.QToolButton()
        self.maxButton.setAccessibleName("btn_max")  
        self.maxButton.setStyleSheet(self.nav_maximize)
        self.maxButton.clicked.connect(self.showMaxRestore)

        self.hideButton = qtw.QToolButton()
        self.hideButton.setAccessibleName("btn_min")  
        self.hideButton.clicked.connect(self.onClickHide)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.hideButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.maxButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    #####################################################
    ## TITLE BAR MINIMIZE, MAXIMIZE, CLOSE METHODS
    #####################################################
    def onClickClose(self):
        main.close()
            
    def onClickHide(self):
        main.showMinimized()

    def showMaxRestore(self):
        # QWidget.showNormal() # https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#showNormal
        #-- Restores the widget after it has been maximized or minimized.
        if(self.maximizedWindow):
            # self.prevGeo = self.geometry() 
            main.showNormal()
            self.maximizedWindow = False
            self.maxButton.setStyleSheet(self.nav_maximize)
        else:
        # QWidget.showMaximized() # https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#showMaximized
        #-- Shows the widget maximized.
            self.prevGeo = self.geometry() # save current window geometry. this helps with centering the mouse cursor in the titlebar
            main.showMaximized()
            self.maximizedWindow = True
            self.maxButton.setStyleSheet(self.nav_normal)
    
    # EVENT FUNCTIONS
    # window will maximize if mouse cursor is positioned at less then 10 pixels in y-coordinate
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.globalPosition().y() < 10:
            self.showMaxRestore() # maximize window

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # getting previous mouse x and y coordinates
        self.prevMousePos = event.scenePosition()
        self.pressing = True
        
        if event.type() == qtc.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
            self.showMaxRestore()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event): # this is responsible for the mouse drag on title bar

        if(self.maximizedWindow): 
        # if the window is moved while maximized, 
        # it is automatically returned to its normal state upon mouse drag
                main.showNormal()
                self.maximizedWindow= False
                self.maxButton.setStyleSheet(self.nav_maximize)
                # mouse cursor re-positioning on the window
                self.prevMousePos = qtc.QPointF((self.prevGeo.width()*.5), (self.prevGeo.height()*.5)) # setting the mouse position to be exactly at the center of the titlebar

        if self.pressing: # this is for moving the window
            # GLOBAL POSITION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67723421/deprecationwarning-function-when-moving-app-removed-titlebar-pyside6
            mousePosition = event.globalPosition()
            pos = mousePosition-self.prevMousePos
            x = pos.x() 
            y = pos.y() 
            main.move(x,y)
      
    #####################################################
    ##                      END
    #####################################################


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage("Ready")

        self.current_editor = self.create_editor()
        self.current_editor.setFocus()
        self.text_editors = []

          # WINDOW FLAGS: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html?highlight=windowminimizebuttonhint
        self.setMinimumSize(400,250)
        self.resize(700,500)
        self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint|
                            qtc.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint|
                            qtc.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
                            qtc.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint  # make window on top of taskbar
                            )

        self.title_bar  = TitleBar(self)
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabBar().setMovable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.remove_editor)
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.change_text_editor)
        self.tabs.tabBar().setMovable(True)
        
        self._createToolBars()

        # Cannot set QxxLayout directly on the QMainWindow
        # Need to create a QWidget and set it as the central widget
        widget = qtw.QWidget()
        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.title_bar,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.file_toolbar,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs,3)
        layout.setSpacing(0) 
        widget.setLayout(layout)
     
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.new_tab()
        self.closeTab()
        self._createActions()
        self._connectActions()

    def create_editor(self):
        current_editor = qtw.QTextEdit()
        # Set the tab stop width to around 33 pixels which is
        # about 8 spaces
        current_editor.setTabStopDistance(33)
        return current_editor

    def change_text_editor(self, index):
        if index < len(self.text_editors):
            self.current_editor = self.text_editors[index]

    def remove_editor(self, index):
        if self.tabs.count() < 2: 
            return True
  
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)
        if index < len(self.text_editors):
            del self.text_editors[index]
        
    def closeTab(self): 
        close_tab = qtg.QShortcut(qtg.QKeySequence("Ctrl+W"), self)
        close_tab.activated.connect(lambda:self.remove_editor(self.tabs.currentIndex()))

    def close(self): # close entire program
        qtw.QApplication.quit()

    def new_tab(self, checked = False, title = "Untitled.txt"):
        self.widget = qtw.QMainWindow()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.widget, title)
        self.tabs.setCurrentWidget(self.current_editor) # set the current tab selected as current widget
        
        self.current_editor = self.create_editor() # create a QTextEdit
        self.text_editors.append(self.current_editor) # add current editor to the array list 
        self.widget.setCentralWidget(self.current_editor)
    
    def open_document(self):
        options = qtw.QFileDialog.Options()
        self.filename, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open File',".",
            "(*.notes);;Text Files (*.txt);;Python Files (*.py)",
            options=options
        )
        if self.filename:
            with open(self.filename,"rt") as file:
                content = file.read()
                self.current_editor = self.create_editor() 
                currentIndex = self.tabs.addTab(self.current_editor, str(self.filename))   # use that widget as the new tab
                self.current_editor.setText(content) # set the contents of the file as the text
                self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(currentIndex) # make current opened tab be on focus
                
    def _createToolBars(self):
        # create toolbars
        self.file_toolbar = self.addToolBar("File")
        self.file_toolbar.setIconSize(qtc.QSize(22,22))
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.new_action)
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.save_action)

    def _createActions(self):
        # FILE MENU
        self.new_action = qtg.QAction(qtg.QIcon("./icons/new_file.png"),"New", self)
        self.open_action = qtg.QAction(qtg.QIcon("./icons/folder.png"),"Open", self)
        self.save_action = qtg.QAction(qtg.QIcon("./icons/save.png"),"Save", self)
        self.exit_action = qtg.QAction(qtg.QIcon("./icons/close.png"), "Exit", self)
   
        self.new_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        self.open_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        self.save_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        self.exit_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+Q")

        self.new_action.setToolTip("New file")
        self.open_action.setToolTip("Open a file")
        self.save_action.setToolTip("Save a file")
        self.exit_action.setToolTip("Exit Program")

    def _connectActions(self):
        # Connect File actions
        self.new_action.triggered.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.open_action.triggered.connect(self.open_document)
        self.save_action.triggered.connect(self.save_document)
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

    def save_document (self):
        if not self.current_editor.document().isModified():
            self.statusBar().showMessage("There are no texts to be saved!")
        else:
            # Only open dialog if there is no filename yet
            #PYQT5 Returns a tuple in PyQt5, we only need the filename
            options = qtw.QFileDialog.Options()
            file_filter = 'Notes_ file (*.notes);; Text file (*.txt);; Python file (*.py)'
            if not self.filename:
                self.filename = qtw.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,caption='Save File',directory=".",filter=file_filter,initialFilter='Notes Files (*.notes)')[0] # zero index is required, otherwise it would throw an error if no selection was made
            
            if self.filename:

                # We just store the contents of the text file along with the
                # format in html, which Qt does in a very nice way for us
                with open(self.filename,"wt") as file:
                    file.write(self.current_editor.toHtml())
                    print(self.tabs.currentIndex())
                    print(str(self.filename))
                    self.tabs.setTabText(self.tabs.currentIndex(), str(self.filename)) # renames the current tabs with the filename
                    self.statusBar().showMessage(f"Saved to {self.filename}")
                    
                self.changesSaved = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.setStyleSheet(
        """
          QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_close"] {
                image: url(./icons/nav_close.png);
                background: #161a21;
                border: none;
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_close"]:hover {
                image: url(./icons/colored_close.png);
                background: #161a21;
                border: none;
            }    
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_min"] {
                image: url(./icons/nav_minimize.png);
                background: #161a21;
                border: none;
                padding-right: 3px;
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_min"]:hover {
                image: url(./icons/colored_minimize.png);
                background: #161a21;
                border: none;
                padding-right: 3px;
            }
        """
    )
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

thanks in advance for any feedbacks or suggestions.

Comment: Your question is confusing: both "the vertical sequence is" and "how do i make it show as" have the same order. Besides, sorry but StackOverflow is ***not*** a debugging service nor a help desk, and questions should always be self-contained (not rely on external resources, especially if they are repositories, since their content may change and make the question invalid). Also, sorry again, but the fact that you've been struggling with your program for a long time is completely meaningless for us. We're eager to help, but we won't do *your* work for you. Please provide a *proper* [mre].

Comment: ok, understandable. removing parts on the code now.

Comment: i removed the styling, i think it's clearer now. i am just confused with the toolbar. it shows on top of the titlebar if i add it normally. i am thinking of putting the toolbar on a separate qmainwindow and placing it below the titlebar.. although not sure how to do it.

Comment: btw, i saw your answer to the topic. i think it's perfect. i would like to use it, but i am just not good enough to understand your code. i used S Nick answer instead since it's easier to follow

Comment: change the widget adding sequence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this:

```
self._createToolBars()
```

from `new_tab`.

Add this:

```
    file_toolbar = self.addToolBar("File")
    file_toolbar.setIconSize(qtc.QSize(22,22))
    
    file_toolbar.addAction(self.new_action)
    file_toolbar.addAction(self.open_action)
```

before `widget = qtw.QWidget()` in **init**

Then change this:

```
    layout.addWidget(self.title_bar,1)
    layout.addWidget(self.tabs,2)
```

to this:

```
    layout.addWidget(self.title_bar,1)
    layout.addWidget(file_toolbar,2)
    layout.addWidget(self.tabs,3)
```

Now you should have the desired order...

PS: I do not have the same icons as you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**complete PyQt6** version of **@A. Herlas** solution above:

EDIT:

- finally got to fix the issue with the mouse cursor not exactly centering on the
  titlebar if window maximized and then moused dragged [10/25/2022]

Code:

```
# TODO: PySide6/PyQt5 to PyQt6 conversion
# -> In order to call "Window" or "WindowText" in QPallete, you need to use the enum "ColorRole" 
#   like this: (QtGui.QPalette.ColorRole.Window) = read here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpalette.html
#
# -> "qtc.Qt.white" does not work anymore in PyQt6, use the enum "GlobalColor"
#   like this: (QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.black) = read here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html
#   
# -> error: AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'FramelessWindowHint'. solution: use enum "WindowType"
#   like this: (QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint) = read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69747328/pyqt6-attributeerror-qt
#
# -> error: AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'AlignCenter'. solution: use enum "AlignmentFlag" 
#   like this: (QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter) = read here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum
#
# -> error: AttributeError: type object 'QSizePolicy' has no attribute 'Expanding'. solution: use enum "Policy"
#   like this: (QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding) = read here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizepolicy.html


import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt6 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt6 import QtGui as qtg
from pathlib import Path


class TitleBar(qtw.QWidget):
    height = 35
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(parent)

        self.nav_maximize = """
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"] {
                image: url(./icons/nav_maximize.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: nobutton_stylene;
                padding-right: 3px; 
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]:hover {
                image: url(./icons/colored_maximize.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
            }
        """

        self.nav_normal =  """
                QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]{
                    image: url(./icons/nav_normal.png);
                    background: #1c2028;
                    border: none;
                    
                }
                QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]:hover{
                    image: url(./icons/colored_normal.png);
                    background: #1c2028;
                    border: none;
                    
                }
            """

        ### for window movement ###
        self.prevGeo = self.geometry() # save window geometry: QtCore.QRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        self.pressing = False
        self.maximizedWindow=False
        ### [ end ] ###
        
        self.current_editor = self.parent().create_editor()
        self.current_editor.setFocus()
        self.text_editors = []
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True) 
        self.tabs.tabBar().setMovable(True)

        self.parent()._createActions()
        self.parent()._connectActions()
        
        self.layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,10,0) 
        
        self.menubar = qtw.QMenuBar()
  
        file_menu = self.menubar.addMenu('File')
        file_menu.addAction(self.parent().new_action)
        file_menu.addAction(self.parent().open_action)
        file_menu.addSeparator()
        file_menu.addAction(self.parent().exit_action)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.menubar) 

        self.window_title = qtw.QLabel("Visual Studio Code") # Notes
        self.window_title.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.window_title.setAccessibleName("lbl_title") 
        self.window_title.setFixedHeight(self.height)
        self.layout.addStretch(1) # this stretches the self.window_title qlabel to take-up all the remaining space
        self.layout.addWidget(self.window_title)

        self.setSizePolicy(qtw.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, qtw.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        self.maximizedWindow=False
       
        self.closeButton = qtw.QToolButton() 
        self.closeButton.setAccessibleName("btn_close")                           
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.onClickClose)

        self.maxButton = qtw.QToolButton()
        self.maxButton.setAccessibleName("btn_max")  
        self.maxButton.setStyleSheet(self.nav_maximize)
        self.maxButton.clicked.connect(self.showMaxRestore)

        self.hideButton = qtw.QToolButton()
        self.hideButton.setAccessibleName("btn_min")  
        self.hideButton.clicked.connect(self.onClickHide)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.hideButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.maxButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    #####################################################
    ## TITLE BAR MINIMIZE, MAXIMIZE, CLOSE METHODS
    #####################################################
    def onClickClose(self):
        main.close()
            
    def onClickHide(self):
        main.showMinimized()

    def showMaxRestore(self):
        # QWidget.showNormal() # https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#showNormal
        #-- Restores the widget after it has been maximized or minimized.
        if(self.maximizedWindow):
            # self.prevGeo = self.geometry() 
            main.showNormal()
            self.maximizedWindow = False
            self.maxButton.setStyleSheet(self.nav_maximize)
        else:
        # QWidget.showMaximized() # https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#showMaximized
        #-- Shows the widget maximized.
            self.prevGeo = self.geometry() # save current window geometry. this helps with centering the mouse cursor in the titlebar
            main.showMaximized()
            self.maximizedWindow = True
            self.maxButton.setStyleSheet(self.nav_normal)
    
    # EVENT FUNCTIONS
    # window will maximize if mouse cursor is positioned at less then 10 pixels in y-coordinate
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.globalPosition().toPoint().y() < 10:
            self.showMaxRestore() # maximize window
            return

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # getting previous mouse x and y coordinates
        self.prevMousePos = event.scenePosition() # coordinates of prev mouse position
        # print("previous mouse pos",self.prevMousePos)
        self.pressing = True
        
        if event.type() == qtc.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonDblClick:
            self.showMaxRestore()
            return

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event): # this is responsible for the mouse drag on title bar

        if(self.maximizedWindow): 
        # if the window is moved while maximized, 
        # it is automatically returned to its normal state upon mouse drag
                main.showNormal()
                self.maximizedWindow= False
                self.maxButton.setStyleSheet(self.nav_maximize)
                # mouse cursor re-positioning on the window
                self.prevMousePos = qtc.QPointF((self.prevGeo.width()*.5), (self.prevGeo.height()*.5)) # setting the mouse position to be exactly at the center of the titlebar

        if self.pressing: # this is for moving the window
            # GLOBAL POSITION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67723421/deprecationwarning-function-when-moving-app-removed-titlebar-pyside6
            mousePosition = event.globalPosition()
            print("mousePosition",mousePosition)
            pos = mousePosition-self.prevMousePos
            # "toPoint()" rounds the the float value of QPointF to the nearest integer
            x = pos.toPoint().x()
            y = pos.toPoint().y() 
            main.move(x,y) # .move() only accepts integer values that's why we use .toPoint()

      
    #####################################################
    ##                      END
    #####################################################


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage("Ready")

        self.current_editor = self.create_editor()
        self.current_editor.setFocus()
        self.text_editors = []

        # WINDOW FLAGS: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html?highlight=windowminimizebuttonhint
        self.setMinimumSize(400,250)
        self.resize(700,500)
        self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint|
                            qtc.Qt.WindowType.WindowMaximizeButtonHint|
                            qtc.Qt.WindowType.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
                            qtc.Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint  # make window on top of taskbar
                            )

        self.title_bar  = TitleBar(self)
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabBar().setMovable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.remove_editor)
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.change_text_editor)
        self.tabs.tabBar().setMovable(True)
        
        self._createToolBars()
        
        # Cannot set QxxLayout directly on the QMainWindow
        # Need to create a QWidget and set it as the central widget
        widget = qtw.QWidget()
        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.title_bar,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.file_toolbar,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs,3)
        layout.setSpacing(0) 
        widget.setLayout(layout)
     
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.new_tab()
        self.closeTab()
        self._createActions()
        self._connectActions()

    def create_editor(self):
        current_editor = qtw.QTextEdit()
        # Set the tab stop width to around 33 pixels which is
        # about 8 spaces
        current_editor.setTabStopDistance(33)
        return current_editor

    def change_text_editor(self, index):
        if index < len(self.text_editors):
            self.current_editor = self.text_editors[index]

    def remove_editor(self, index):
        if self.tabs.count() < 2: 
            return True

        self.tabs.removeTab(index)
        if index < len(self.text_editors):
            del self.text_editors[index]
        
    def closeTab(self): 
        close_tab = qtg.QShortcut(qtg.QKeySequence("Ctrl+W"), self)
        close_tab.activated.connect(lambda:self.remove_editor(self.tabs.currentIndex()))

    def close(self): # close entire program
        qtw.QApplication.quit()

    def new_tab(self, checked = False, title = "Untitled.txt"):
        self.widget = qtw.QMainWindow()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.widget, title)
        self.tabs.setCurrentWidget(self.current_editor) # set the current tab selected as current widget
        
        self.current_editor = self.create_editor() # create a QTextEdit
        self.text_editors.append(self.current_editor) # add current editor to the array list 
        self.widget.setCentralWidget(self.current_editor)
    
    def open_document(self):
        # guide on pyqt6: QFileDialog = read here: https://zetcode.com/pyqt6/dialogs/
        home_dir = str(Path.home())
        self.filename, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open File',".",
            "Text Files (*.txt);;Python Files (*.py)",
            home_dir
        )
        if self.filename:
            with open(self.filename,"rt") as file:
                content = file.read()
                self.current_editor = self.create_editor() 
                currentIndex = self.tabs.addTab(self.current_editor, str(self.filename))   # use that widget as the new tab
                self.current_editor.setText(content) # set the contents of the file as the text
                self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(currentIndex) # make current opened tab be on focus
                
    def _createToolBars(self):
        # create toolbars
        self.file_toolbar = self.addToolBar("File")
        self.file_toolbar.setIconSize(qtc.QSize(22,22))
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.new_action)
        self.file_toolbar.addAction(self.open_action)
        
    def _createActions(self): 
        # FILE MENU
        self.new_action = qtg.QAction(qtg.QIcon("./icons/new_file.png"),"New", self)
        self.open_action = qtg.QAction(qtg.QIcon("./icons/folder.png"),"Open", self)
        self.exit_action = qtg.QAction(qtg.QIcon("./icons/close.png"), "Exit", self)
   
        self.new_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        self.open_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        self.exit_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+Q")

        self.new_action.setToolTip("New file")
        self.open_action.setToolTip("Open a file")
        self.exit_action.setToolTip("Exit Program")

    def _connectActions(self):
        # Connect File actions
        self.new_action.triggered.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.open_action.triggered.connect(self.open_document)
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(qtw.QStyleFactory.create("Fusion")) # ['windowsvista', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
    print(qtw.QStyleFactory.keys())
    # DARKER COLOR OR LIGHTER: https://pinetools.com/darken-color
    # COLOR READABILITY CHECKER: https://coolors.co/contrast-checker/dfdcd1-1c2028
    # QPallete documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpalette.html
    palette = qtg.QPalette()
    palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ColorRole.Window, qtg.QColor("#1c2028")) # general background color
    palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ColorRole.WindowText, qtg.QColor("#BFBDB6")) # for the window title
    palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ColorRole.Button, qtg.QColor("#1c2028")) # overflow buttons color for the qtabbar
    palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ColorRole.Window, qtg.QColor("#1c2028")) # menu border color
    palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ColorRole.Text, qtg.QColor("#BFBDB6")) # menu unhighlited text color
    palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ColorRole.Base, qtg.QColor("#1c2028")) # menu unhighlited bg color
    palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ColorRole.Highlight, qtg.QColor("#0086b6")) # menu mouse hover highlight color 
    palette.setColor(qtg.QPalette.ColorRole.HighlightedText, qtg.QColor("#000000")) # menu highlighted text color 
    app.setPalette(palette)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.setStyleSheet(
         """
            /* css styling properties: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-bottom_style.asp */
            
            QMainWindow{ border-style: none;}
            QStatusBar { color: #BFBDB6; background: #1c2028; }
            QMenuBar::item:pressed {  color: #BFBDB6; background: #1c2028; }
            QMenuBar::item { color: #BFBDB6; background: #1c2028; }
            
            /* styling Qmenu: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu */
            
            QTextEdit QMenu::item {color: #BFBDB6; font-weight: normal;} /* for context menu> right click -> textedit*/
            QTextEdit QMenu::item:selected { /* when user selects item using mouse or keyboard */
                background-color: #0086b6;
                color: #000;
            }
            
            QTabWidget::pane { border: none; }
            QTabBar::tab { border: none; }
            QTabBar::tab:top:selected { background: #161a21;}
            QTabBar::tab:top:!selected { background: #1c2028; }
            QTabBar::close-button { image: url(./icons/close_default.png); margin: 2px}
            QTabBar::close-button:hover { image: url(./icons/close_active.png);  margin: 2px}
            QTabBar::tab:selected {
                color: #ffb454;
                background: #1c2028;
                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            }
            
            QTabBar::tab:!selected {
                color: #BFBDB6;
                background: #1c2028;
                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            }
            QTabBar::tab:top, QTabBar::tab:bottom {
                min-width: 8ex;
                margin-right: -1px;
                padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
            }
            QTextEdit
            {
                border: none;
                font: "Consolas";
                color: #BFBDB6;
                background: #161a21;
                selection-background-color: #ffb454;
                selection-color: #000000;
            }
            QMenuBar
            {
                color: #BFBDB6;
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
                border-style: none;
            }
            QMenuBar::item:selected 
            { 
                color: #BFBDB6;
                background: #1c2028; 
            } 
            QToolBar
            {
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
                border-style: none;
            }
            /*  -----------------------------//
                -  The css below affects the QToolbar buttons (or any QToolButton)
                -----------------------------//
            */
                QToolButton::hover{
                background-color: #1c2028;
            }
            /*  ---------- [end] ------------*/

                QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]{
                image: url(./icons/nav_normal.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;  
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]:hover{
                image: url(./icons/colored_normal.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"] {
                image: url(./icons/nav_maximize.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: nobutton_stylene;
                padding-right: 3px; 
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_max"]:hover {
                image: url(./icons/colored_maximize.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
            }
            QMenuBar{
                color: #fff;
                font: "Consolas";
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 3px; 
            }
            QLabel[accessibleName="lbl_title"]{
                background-color: #1c2028; 
                font-size: 13px;
                font: "Consolas";
                padding-right: 425px;
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_close"] {
                image: url(./icons/nav_close.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_close"]:hover {
                image: url(./icons/colored_close.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
            }    
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_min"] {
                image: url(./icons/nav_minimize.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
                padding-right: 3px;
            }
            QToolButton[accessibleName="btn_min"]:hover {
                image: url(./icons/colored_minimize.png);
                background: #1c2028;
                border: none;
                padding-right: 3px;
            }
            QScrollBar:vertical {
                border: none;
                width: 14px;
                margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
                background-color: #1c2028;
                border-radius: 0px;
            }
            QScrollBar:handle:vertical {
                background-color: #292c35;
            }
            QScrollBar:handle:vertical:hover {
                background-color: #4c4a4a;
            }
            QScrollBar:handle:vertical:pressed {
                background-color: #5c5b5b;
            }
            QScrollBar:horizontal {
                border: none;
                height: 14px;
                margin: 0px 0 0 0;
                background-color: #1c2028;
                border-radius: 0px;
            }
            QScrollBar:handle:horizontal {
                background-color: #292c35;
            }
            QScrollBar:handle:horizontal:hover {
                background-color: #4c4a4a;
            }
            QScrollBar:handle:horizontal:pressed {
                background-color: #5c5b5b;
            }
            /*  -----------------------------//
                -  The css below removes the QScrollBar's Arrow keys both aesthetically AND functionally
                -----------------------------//
            */
            QScrollBar::left-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal,
            QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal{
                border: none;
                background-color: none;
                color: none;
                width:0px;
                height:0px;
            }
            QScrollBar::sub-line, QScrollBar::add-line{
                border: none;
                background-color: none;
                width:0px;
                height:0px;
            }
            /*  ---------- [end] ----------  */
        """
    )
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```